# Mockito : Mock groovy rest client call

Tags: groovy, mockito

I am using Mockito with Groovy to unit test some rest calls using the Groovy rest client.

How can I mock the bpmApiRestClient.get call in the updatePhase method below?

```
@Service
public class PhasesBPMServiceImpl implements PhasesBPMService {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PhasesBPMServiceImpl.class)

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper

    @Autowired
    BPMConfig bpmConfig

    @Autowired
    JsonSlurper jsonSlurper

    @Autowired
    GetMaintenanceActivitiesPhasesCurrentResponseTransformer getMaintenanceActivitiesPhasesCurrentResponseTransformer

    @Autowired
    PutMaintenanceActivityPhaseRequestTransformer putMaintenanceActivityPhaseRequestTransformer

public void updatePhase(
    String loggedInUsernameEncoded,
    String phaseDefinitionKey, 
    String activityId, 
    Reader reader) {

    def bpmApiRestClient = new BpmRestClient(bpmConfig)
    try {
        def processInstancePhases = bpmApiRestClient.get path: 'task', query: [ processInstanceId: activityId ] 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        logger.error "Error occurred while updating phase details. Error Message [${e?.message}]. Error Cause [${e?.cause}]"
        throw e
    }
    finally {
        bpmApiRestClient.shutdown()
    }
}
```

At one stage I had things working as per the unit test below but once I refactored bpmApiRestClient to be instantiated inside the method rather than at the class level the mocking stopped working.

```
class PhasesBPMServiceImplPutMaintenanceActivitiesByActivityIdPhasesNameTest {

    def restClient, responseTransformer, objectMapper, jsonSlurper, bpmConfig

    void init() {
        restClient = Mockito.mock(RESTClient)
        when(restClient.get(anyObject())).thenReturn([data: [
                [    // get current task for process id
                    id: "2",
                    name: "Waiting to be allocated",
                    assignee: "Cosmo Kramer",
                    created: "2016-11-16T15:10:29"
                ]
            ]])

        responseTransformer = new PutMaintenanceActivityPhaseRequestTransformer(responseBaseUrl: '/maintenance/activities')
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapperConfig().getObjectMapper()
        jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        bpmConfig = new BPMConfig(maintenanceProcessName:'Maintenance_Activity_Process',
        baseUrl:'http://localhost:12378/v1/camunda/rest/')

    }

    @Test
    void testUpdatePhaseSuccess() {
        // setup
        init()
        PhasesBPMServiceImpl service =
                new PhasesBPMServiceImpl(bpmConfig: bpmConfig,
                putMaintenanceActivityPhaseRequestTransformer: responseTransformer,
                objectMapper: objectMapper,
                jsonSlurper: new JsonSlurper())
        // invoke
        try {
            def request = getClass().getResourceAsStream('/in/putPhaseRequest.json').text
            def response = service.updatePhase('rriviere', 'Unallocated', '7', new StringReader(request))
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            fail()
        }
    }

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You refactored your code to be untestable as the `bpmApiRestClient` cannot be mocked. Make it a dependency of this class (instead of bpmConfig) or refactor retrieving the results into a separate class.

Comment: I fully agree the best approach is inversion of control (wire the classes externally), but if you **had** to perform mocking on a class constructor, you can use Powermock, see this [blog post](http://benkiefer.com/blog/2013/04/23/powermockito-constructor-mocking/)

Comment: thanks for your comments guys ! I now understand there are some technical challenges in mocking a local method object. Looks like if I did want to get it going Powermock is an option.